# Using setState cause blank page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent and one child component. The parent passes setState to the child as props.

```
<SkillFunc handleChange={this.setState.bind(this)} />
```

Here's how the child uses it

```
props.handleChange({rating: count});
```

The problem is that doing this causes a blank page. Nothing renders, completely white. The error in the console is (There's nothing above.):

```
The above error occurred in the <SkillFunc> component:

at SkillFunc (webpack-internal:///./components/common/components/skillFunc.tsx:26:70)
```

In line 26,

```
var _React$useState = react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default().useState({
0: true,
1: true,
2: true,
3: true,
4: true
```

}),

But I assume it meant this:

```
const [ratings, setRatings] = React.useState(
    {
        0: true,
        1: true,
        2: true,
        3: true,
        4: true
    }
);
```

I tried to pass {console.log} as props to SkillFunc and it worked perfectly. It only happens when I use the setState. I don't really know how to fix this. Grateful for any help.

Edit: I have solved it by putting the props.handleChange inside the function which gets called when the component state changes.

Comment: @pilchard Thanks for the reply. In the parent I use setState because it's a Class and I need to get value from the child component which uses the useState (setRatings)

Comment: I see, I had a feeling. You should include minimum component code to clarify this.

Comment: `The above error occurred`

Can you also post the above error?

Answer (score -1):

That feature is called lifting state
look it here https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-poitras-hiv1fi

Also, you can see it on React DOCS

let me know if you got it!!